# Pine script = Change values in code string for alert(message = ) to trading bot

Tags: json, string, bots, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I can't manage to change 123, 1 and 0 to numbers I should be able to choose in the input user interface. It is for the robot bot alert() message, which otherwise must be identical.

As it is now, it's terribly difficult because I have to edit the strategy code for each stock I want to change something for.

The code string must be identical in its entirety otherwise, not divided or changed otherwise the trading robot will not understand.

```
Numbers up to 10000 =              "TradingviewID": "123"
Numbers up to 10000 =              "Quantity": "1"
Number with the options: 0, 1, 2 = "Pricetype": "0"
```

Here is the code string:

```
alert(message = '{"TradingviewID": "123", "Quantity": "1", "Pricetype": "0"}')
```

I've tried a little bit of everything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the input function and change the values from the script's settings instead. To convert integers to strings, use the `str.tostring()`:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

idInput     = input.int(123,   "TradingviewID", minval = 0, maxval = 10000)
qtyInput    = input.int(1,     "Quantity", minval = 0, maxval = 10000)
typeInput   = input.int(0,     "Pricetype", options = [0, 1, 2])

alertMessage = '{"TradingviewID": "' + str.tostring(idInput) + '", "Quantity": "' + str.tostring(qtyInput) + '", "Pricetype": "' + str.tostring(typeInput) + '"}'

alert(message = alertMessage)

if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    label.new(bar_index, close, alertMessage)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, great, I have tested it with alarm in the strategy.
Just need to figure out how to change the code to get "Quantity": "0" for sell. I can't have the same one for both buying and selling. Then value 0 is sell and a value 1 or higher is buy. I should probably succeed, but if you have time and want to, please let me know. Wish you understand what I mean.

Thanks anyway! I have more code problems, if you see a post from me, please help me! You're really good! Thanks

Comment: You can replace input with a manual calculation of the variable `qtyInput`, which depends on your boolean values of `buy` and `sell`, for example: `int qtyInput = buy ? 1 : sell ? 0 : na`